# How to get the attribues (alt and title) of an image import with ACF

Tags: images, advanced-custom-fields

I use the ACF plugin to build oone of my page.
Inside this one, i load 4 images.
How can I get attached image alt ?
I tried with  "$alt = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);" and a lot of other things my nothing works.

```
<img src="<?php the_field('image_1');?>" alt="$alt">
```

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already in the docs. Try this:

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

For easier debugging, try this: `var_dump($image);` to print out the `$image` variable to know what is in `$image`. You can also put `var_dump($image)` inside `<pre>` tag for better reading.

Comment: That's not working :(
`$image['url']` doesn't work, I have to write  only `$image` to get the url. I can't get 'alt' with `echo $image['alt']`

Comment: I know what problem is. You must set Return Value to `Image Object`. And try my code again. It will work! :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in the php code, how can I do that ?

Comment: It's in the ACF Fields Setting. When you add an Image Field, scroll down a bit, you will find Return Value section.